# Not able to deploy Spring MVC 4.0 Webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

1) web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>gamesWS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

2) rest-servlet.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.service.games" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

3) Java class-

```
package com.service.games;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result = "Hello " + name;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I created a `gamesWS.war` file and placed it in the webapps folder of Tomcat server.

Started the server without any error.

But, when trying to access the webserv using localhost:8080/gamesWS/service/greeting/text

I am getting an error - `HTTP Status 404 : Requested resource not available.`

I tried checking - jdk version mismatch, proper folder to place of war file. Can someone please  point me what I might be missing here?

Snap shot of the firebug console -

[image]

Comment: I think if you turn up the logging level to debug, Spring will print out a list of the request mappings.  You could then check the list and see if you see the one you expect.  You are not specifying an "accepts" header, so I don't think that would be the issue.  Are you maybe doing a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: I'm using this url... `localhost:8080/gamesWS/service/greeting/text` This is a get call, am i correct here?

Comment: If you are using a browser to connect, I would recommend using some debug tools to see what is being sent/received.  You would then be able to see exactly what exchange is happening.  I often find in this instances that what I thought I was sending was not what I was sending.

Comment: firebug says its a GET request but unfortunately we cant investigate any further with this, do we? Sharing the snapshot.

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing commons-logging jar. Working now. Thank you for looking into this.